# PG_DUMP on Replica DB server Error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I have a master - slave configuration with 9.4 version, but there is no WAL streaming replication configured. Customer simply copy xlog files on network share and replica applies it.

I need to run pg_dump from replica although I face with error.
What do I do:

1. SELECT pg_xlog_replay_pause()
2. Run pg_dump on replica server
3. SELECT pg_xlog_replay_resume()

Immediately I receive after pg_xlog_replay_pause()

```
ERROR:  recovery is not in progress
```

And when the command of pg_dump starts I see:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  cannot assign TransactionIds during recovery
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT pg_export_snapshot()
```

Questions:

1. Does it mean I can't do pg_dump from replica? I have a feeling that in case of wal streaming replication it would be possible. Correct me if I'm wrong.
2. I can't find any information for SELECT pg_xlog_replay_pause() / SELECT pg_xlog_replay_resume() works only with wal streaming setup. 
   Can someone tell if this true?

Thanks in advance.

Customer's setup is:
They copy xlog to network share and  replica recovery.conf consist of

```
standby_mode = 'on'
restore_command = 'if exist A:\\Logs\\From_Master_DB\\%f (copy A:\\Logs\\From_master_DB\\%f  %p) else (exit /b 1)'
archive_cleanup_command = '"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\pg_archivecleanup"  A:\\Logs\\From_Master_DB %r && "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\pg_archivecleanup"  D:\\PG-SQL\\data\\pg_xlog %r'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Comment: What are the options passed to `pg_dump` ?

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I try a directory type of backup:
pg_dump" -w -h localhost -U USER -Z3 -Fd -j 12 -f %BACKUP_PATH%\%DUMPFILE_DB% %DB_NAME%

Comment: With streaming replication, you can definitely do a `pg_dump` on a replica.  I am not sure how it looks like without.  Also, the pair of functions can be used in both modes, as https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-admin.html suggests.  But in the first place: why are you pausing replication?  `pg_dump` is guaranteed to produce a consistent backup: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Hello dezso, thanks for reply.
First, my understanding is based on this doc:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html#HOT-STANDBY-CONFLICT
If I understand it right, any operation in this case it's a copy command is a transaction which potentially can affect on applying xlog on the replica.
So by pausing the xlog apply, - there won't be any disruption of  pg_dump process, I might be wrong here though. 
As for the pg_dump, thanks for the link, I will check it right away for better understanding.

Comment: Second, I was also surprised by the behaviour of the fucntions, it runs fine, but I do not receive 't' or 'f' result, although pg_is_xlog_replay_paused() returns the correct status.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel `pg_dump` against a replica is not supported cleanly until v10.

You can either drop the `-j`, run the dump against the master rather than the replica, or you can use `--no-synchronized-snapshots` which will make your backup be potentially inconsistent.

Pausing the recovery might cure the consistency problem with use of `--no-synchronized-snapshots`, but the pause must be run on the replica, not on the master, which is what you seem to doing.